# why is my resultset containing only one result when it was supposed to get two results

Tags: prepared-statement, resultset, scriptlet

I executed the same query in my db interface directly and got two rows as result... I thought i should be getting same here too... but it is returning only one and for the second it says column index out of range 2>1 !!!

```
session= request.getSession();
String name=(String)session.getAttribute("user");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mutualfund", "root", "");


Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String qry="SELECT `account_type_id` FROM `cust_accounts` WHERE `cust_id`=\""+name+"\"";
ResultSet rs =  statement.executeQuery(qry) ;


if(!rs.next())
{
    out.println("Server Down.. Please try again later ");
} 
else {
    String one=rs.getString(1);
    String two=rs.getString(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't asking for two rows, it's asking for two columns, and your query only supplies one.

```
if (!rs.next()) {
  out.println("nope");
} else {
  String one = rs.getString(1);
  String two = "";
  if (rs.next())
    two = rs.getString(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If you ever expect there to be more than 2 rows though, you should wrap `rs.next()` in a while loop.

Comment: @APPU: 
Absolutely.  Also, be aware the above code will leave `two` as an empty string if only one row is returned!

Comment: @Russell Uhl sheesh!!! i wanna break my head!! thank you so much!! such simple thing!! thankyou :)